# Comparator is not working, I can't find the mistake

Tags: java, sorting, collections, java-8, comparator

I'm trying to sort list of objects fetched from database with comparator object. It should compare **last names** and if **last names** are the same it should compare **first names** and determinate order by them, so if I have list like that:

```
[Jon Doe][Zed Adams][John Adams]
```

It should be sorted like that:

```
[John Adams][Zed Adams][Jon Doe]
```

Now let's take a look at my code:

Comparator class:

```
public class ComparatorContactByName implements Comparator<Contact> {
    @Override
    public int compare(Contact c1, Contact c2) {

        // if lastNames of compared objects are not the same, compare them
        if(!c1.getLastName().toLowerCase().equals(c1.getLastName().toLowerCase())){
            return c1.getLastName().compareTo(c2.getLastName());

        // if lastNames are the same, compare by firstName
        }else if(c1.getLastName().toLowerCase().equals(c1.getLastName().toLowerCase())){
            return c1.getFirstName().toLowerCase().compareTo(c2.getFirstName().toLowerCase());

            // other case like firstName and lastName are the same, compare by id
        }else{
            return c1.getContactId() - c2.getContactId();
        }
    }
}
```

Controller Method:

```
public void getAllContactsSortedByName(){

    List<Contact> allContacts = ContactRepository.listAllContacts();

    Comparator comparatorContactByName = new ComparatorContactByName();

    Collections.sort(allContacts, comparatorContactByName);

    if (allContacts == null) {
        System.out.println("No contact found. ");
    } else {
        for (Contact contact : allContacts) {
            System.out.println(contact.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

After calling this method I'm getting output like this:

```
Contact{contactId= 133, firstName= John, lastName= Adams, email= ja@email.com, groups= [gym]}    
Contact{contactId= 126, firstName= Jon, lastName= Doe, email= jd@email.com, groups= [work, gym]}    
Contact{contactId= 130, firstName= Zed, lastName= Adams, email= za@email.com, groups= [work]}
```

"Zed" should be second, but he is last. Any ideas how to fix this logic?

Comment: In Java 8+: `Comparator.comparing(Contact::getLastName).thenComparing(Concat::getFirstName).thenComparingInt(Contact::getConcatId)`.

Comment: In "`c1.getLastName().toLowerCase().equals(c1.getLastName().toLowerCase())`": you're using `c1` twice. And use `c1.getLastName().equalsIgnoreCase(c2.getLastName())`, anyway.

Comment: in compare() your if statements compare c1 with c1 rather than comparing c1 with c2.

Comment: Note also that the condition of the `else if` is the complement of the condition of the `if`, so you never reach the final `else`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this is what u have done:

```
c1.getLastName().toLowerCase().equals(c1.getLastName().toLowerCase()
```

you are comparing **c1's** last name with **c1's** last name

instead do this:

```
c1.getLastName().toLowerCase().equals(c2.getLastName().toLowerCase()
```

same goes for first name!

Answer (score 1):

Use `Comparator` API:

```
 Comparator<Contact> comparator = 
       Comparator.comparing(Contact::getLastName, String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER)
                 .thenComparing(Concat::getFirstName, String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER)
                 .thenComparingInt(Contact::getContactId);
```

Comment: Is that a case insensitive comparison?

Comment: @Lothar It's using `String.comapreTo` method. It's case sensitive.

Comment: @Lothar For case-insensitive comparison, use `comparing(Contact::getLastName, String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER)`. For language-sensitive comparison, use e.g. `comparing(Contact::getLastName, Collator.getInstance(Locale.US))`.

Comment: @ETO the question contains a case insensitive comparison.